# Perforce different port branching

Tags: perforce, branching-and-merging

How can I branch file from one port to another port. This are to different port Example(port:1833 and port:2434). Is possible on perforce. Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on your question ?  Are you trying to branch a file form one Perforce server instance to a different instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Different ports basically means two completely independent perforce depots. I don't think there is any to create branch mappings in such a situation. You can basically "copy-paste" manually in the two workspaces you would have but ofcourse not what you want to do.

Comment: Better than just copy/paste is to use a Remote Depot from the target server back to the source server and then integrate the code from the one server to the other. Still, they are indeed two independent Perforce depots.